# OpenCV and Anaconda Python

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

How can you import `OpenCV` to run in `Python`?

I ran it on a windows platform. My main problem i ran into was using Python 3.5 (presuming it was the latest) and the latest version of OpenCV but i didn't know that OpenCV sis not compatible with Python 3.5 so online video tutorials on youtube all failed miserably and i couldnt get past the import stage for almost a full day.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Python 3.5 (64bit) & (32bit) with OpenCV
2. Anaconda 3 (64bit) & (32bit) with OpenCV

Using `Anaconda Python 2.7 (64bit)` with `OpenCV` ended up working. Turns out `OpenCV` that I downloaded from the site is for `Python 2.7`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should try Googling the installation of OpenCV. This is an excellent tutorial, for instance: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I ran it on a windows platform. My main problem i ran into was using Python 3.5 (presuming it was the latest) and the latest version of OpenCV but i didn't know that OpenCV sis not compatible with Python 3.5 so online video tutorials on youtube all failed miserably and i couldnt get past the import stage for almost a full day.

Comment: @bjd2385: Thank you for the great site!

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0
```

or

```
conda install -c anaconda opencv=2.4.10
```

It's a bit annoying that you need to know which collection a package is in if it isn't the standard one, but a certain search engine will find it.

Comment: Thanks, will try it.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply activate your conda environment

```
    conda activate "environment name"
```

install opencv using pip

```
    pip install opencv-python
```

simply compile your code in your environment it should work
it should work.